# Grails Ldap Remember Me IllegalArgumentException

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

Im forced again to try to solve this problem of Ldap-remember me functionality and yet again its causing problems.

Currently i have working Grails 2.2.4 application that has support for Ldap authentication, but checking remember me option is resulting in errors as follows :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Dynamic method get<Artefact>Class(artefactName) requires a single String parameter
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.invokeMethod(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:673)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(GormUserDetailsService.groovy:57)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(GormUserDetailsService.groovy:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices.onLoginSuccess(TokenBasedRememberMeServices.java:178)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices.loginSuccess(AbstractRememberMeServices.java:258)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:324)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:298)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:235)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Ive tried various ways to solve this problem, but i just DONT understand the nature of it. It gives me completly zero information about what could go wrong.
If someone faced similar problem, i would be appreciate for some clues. I would like to "remember me" to be working with cookies.

Ldap configuration for remember me :

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.rememberMe.detailsManager.groupSearchBase='ou=LALALAL,O=LALALAL,C=LALALAL'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.rememberMe.usernameMapper.userDnBase='O=LALALAL,C=LALALAL'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.rememberMe.usernameMapper.usernameAttribute="SOME ID"
```

Edit for someone who might need it:

The problem is one line in PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeService

```
UserDetails user = getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(token.getUsername());
```

It wants to use GormUserDetailsService to retrive data about User, but it fails, because of Ldap. There is no database to fetch data from.

Possible fix is to replace UserDetailsService with custom class.

Comment: Can you give an example of where the UserDetailsService class is and what to replace it with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with Custom UserDetails classes and CustomPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeService.